# How to use apply to "extract" a implication in Coq

Tags: logic, coq, proof, coq-tactic

I'll illustrate using an example.

```
H : R -> P -> Q

H0 : R
```

Subgoal:

```
(Q -> P) \ / (P -> Q)
```

so my question is how do I extract out (P->Q). I have R already, but when I do
'apply H in H0', it evaluates everything and gives me Q.

Answer (score 2):

You can do any of:

```
specialize (H H0).
```

to replace H with `H: P -> Q`, or:

```
pose proof (H H0) as H1
```

to introduce `H1: P -> Q`

You can also go forward:

```
right. exact (H H0).
```